# Reading from a MemoryStream using async

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asynchronous

Im using iTextSharp (not that this is relative to iTextSharp) to generate PDF bytes using code similar to the following:

```
Function GetFileBytes() as Byte()
Dim result() As Byte
    Using ms As New MemoryStream

        Dim reader As New PdfReader(pdfForm)
        Dim writer As New PdfStamper(reader, ms)

        Dim fields As AcroFields = writer.AcroFields

        fields.SetField("Customer Name", custInfo.FirstName + " " + custInfo.LastName)

        result = ms.GetBuffer
    End Using
End Function
```

I want to make this an asynchronous task instead, returning Task(Of Byte()) instead, but I'm having problems figuring out how to make my memorystream write in an asynchronous mode, and how to return a Task(Of Byte()) in the process.  Any tips, suggestions?  Thanks!

**EDIT 1**
I wanted to clarify the need for using a Task and using this code, as it seems some comments so far are along the lines of "why are you doing it this way" and "no just do this instead, and I want to politely say "thanks, but I want to do it this way" :)

Here's my scenario, imagine a website that collects data on a few pages, then presents a review screen, and then gives the user the ability to view a PDF containing that data. On the review screen I need to generate a 1 MB PDF file, upload it to BLOB storage, and have it available when the user chooses to download it.

I want to generate and upload the PDF while the user is reviewing the review screen and not when they choose the "view PDF" button.  That code will be done using my example, which is why I'm curious how to create a Task of type Byte().  Any help is always appreciated, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Responding to your edit: this scenario makes sense. Wrap everything in a `Task.Run` call. Be sure to be thread-safe (don't use the HttpContext in the task for example). Also log errors because they might be bugs.

Note, though, that with ASP.NET background work can be aborted at any time (e.g. when the worker process recycles). You have to tolerate suddenly disappearing background work. In your case the PDF might be missing when the user tries to access it. Also, what if it is still being generated when the user tries to download it. Must solve those issues.

Comment: OK, imagine a website that collects data on a few pages, then presents a review screen, and then gives the user the ability to view a PDF containing that data.  On the review screen I need to generate a 1 MB PDF file, upload it to BLOB storage, and have it available when the user chooses to download it.  I want to generate and upload the PDF while the user is reviewing the review screen and not when they choose the "view PDF" button... make sense?

Comment: That makes sense. Note, though, that with ASP.NET background work can be aborted at any time (e.g. when the worker process recycles). You have to tolerate suddenly disappearing background work. In your case the PDF might be missing when the user tries to access it. Also, what if it is still being generated when the user tries to download it. Must solve those issues.

Comment: I have edited the answer to respond to the added information.

Comment: Thanks @usr!  And all very valid points, I'll be taking into account exception handling, checking for the existence of the PDF, etc. before go live.  However I'm stuck on my initial issue.  Any ideas on how I can perform something like a "GetBufferAsync"?  OR... will wrapping everything in a Task.Run like you said resolve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to make is async a simpler approach would be to create a private thread in the class, that thread on page_init will start the process then on Page_LoadComplete the thread would wait using thread.join() and then you would get the function result, but as mentioned the relative speed gain is minimal, consider that threads(or tasks) are really expensive

**Option 2**
create an ajax request to a generic handler that returns the pdf file data, this way no thread involved and better user experience

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="VB" Class="GetFile" %>

Imports System
Imports System.Web
Imports System.IO

Public Class GetFile : Implements IHttpHandler


    Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest        
        context.Response.Clear()        
            If File.Exists(filePath & docName) Then
                context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" & HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(docName))
                context.Response.ContentType = "text/pdf"
                context.Response.WriteFile(filelocation & docName) 'in your case this writes the bites of the generated file, so instead of the path just pass in the data
            End If 
        context.Response.Flush()
        context.Response.End()
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Comment: not if you start the thread in different parts of the page event, on page_init you start it, on page_load you do something else on Page_LoadComplete you get the data waiting for the thread

Comment: Thanks @Fabrizio but I'm not looking to use an HTTPHandler like this given my most recent edit..

Answer (score 0):

> Here's my scenario, imagine a website that collects data on a few pages, then presents a review screen, and then gives the user the ability to view a PDF containing that data. On the review screen I need to generate a 1 MB PDF file, upload it to BLOB storage, and have it available when the user chooses to download it.

Since you refer to "blob storage", I'll assume you're using Azure.

You need a worker role or service to do this reliably. The worker role should just be reading from an Azure queue and generating PDFs.

So, when your web role generates the review screen, before returning the response, it will also place that data into the Azure queue. When your web role is notified that the user accepts the review, then it should (asynchronously) wait until the PDF file is generated.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I appreciate your answer, as well as the links below.  Here's my issue though.. forget everything else we've discussed so far and just say that I want to generate a byte array from a memorystream.  How could I go about doing that in parallel with loading up a page, so I could almost kick that task off "in the background"?  Your methodology described above makes sense, but what I'm trying to do is perform this Azure Queue stuff asynchronously.. it take 3-5 seconds to generate the bytes, and that's the time I'm trying to save.. make sense?

Comment: If by "loading up a page" you mean "do the processing on the server side to generate the page to send to the client", then you *can* use `Task.Run` to generate the bytes and then `await` it before completing the response. However, *parallel* code like this on your server is very risky; it will hurt your scalability and should only be used if you're 100% sure that you will *always* have a very low number of users (e.g., an internal-only website).

Answer (score -1):

(Don't use this code below.. see end of "answer" for reasoning)..

Thanks to everyone for the help.  In the end I was approaching this wrong.  All I needed was to create an Async wrapper function to return my Task(Of Byte())

So if my initial code was this:

```
Function GetFileBytes() as Byte()
    Dim result() As Byte

      Using ms As New MemoryStream

        Dim reader As New PdfReader(pdfForm)
        Dim writer As New PdfStamper(reader, ms)

        Dim fields As AcroFields = writer.AcroFields

        fields.SetField("Customer Name", custInfo.FirstName + " " + custInfo.LastName)

        result = ms.GetBuffer
    End Using
End Function
```

Now, I created a new method called GetFileBytesAsync to return Task(Of Byte()) calling the same GetFileBytes method described above, it's just called using a Task.Factory.StartNew, like so:

```
Public Shared Async Function GetFileBytesAsync() As Task(Of Byte())
        Dim t As Task(Of Byte()) = Task.Factory.StartNew(Function()
                                                             Return GetFileBytes()
                                                         End Function)

        Return Await t

    End Function
```

And in my calling function, I now just use the Result property of my task object to access the byte array.  HTH!

EDIT: OK, so as Stephen Cleary aptly pointed out, I'm doing this all wrong, the above code is not recommended and it isn't doing anything asynchronously.. as a matter of fact its creating new threads to create some blocking code.  Sorry...

I came across this TechEd talk: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2013/DEV-B337 - it's How to Build ASP.NET Web Applications Using Async.  At the 54 Minute Mark it actually indicates that trying to use a "background thread" on an ASP.NET Web Server is wrong, as there are no background threads for use in IIS, and in essence you are taking up threads that could\should be used to respond to web requests.

Comment: So... you're blocking on a fake-asynchronous wrapper? That's like... I don't even... Yeah. -1, at least.

Comment: I have a few blog posts that may help you out: [why you shouldn't do work outside of a request in ASP.NET](http://tinyurl.com/pv9ubp5), [why you shouldn't block on `async` code](http://tinyurl.com/lry96l3), [why you should use `Task.Run` instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew`](http://tinyurl.com/kh93rko), and [slides on server-side `async`](http://tinyurl.com/lf2uo9j) (which includes explanations of why threadpool tasks in web servers are a bad idea). This answer also falls afoul of [Stephen Toub's advice](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx).

Comment: Thanks @StephenCleary I'll read those articles and take another stab.  If this methodology is incorrect, mind checking out my initial post and advise on how I can approach this?  If correct, I'll happily remove this "answer" and post a correct one (or mark yours as such), last thing I want to do is advise incorrectly on SO.